# value of the variable after storage allocation in c++

Tags: c++, c

Is it possible for the compiler to know the value of the variable after storage allocation in c++?
And what is the case with c compiler if the following code is given

```
const int bufsize = 100;
char buf[bufsize];
```

The textual explanation is as follows:
"In C, you will get an error, even though it seems like a rational thing to
do. Because bufsize occupies storage somewhere, the C compiler
cannot know the value at compile time."
Why is it said so?

Comment: Is it C or C++? They are not the same thing, and the respective answers differ significantly.

Comment: "the value of the variable"? which variable? your quote indicates you are asking for the size of the array in bytes?

Comment: Note that "the C compiler cannot know the value at compile time" is false but irrelevant. The C compiler *can* know the value of `bufsize` at compile time, but the compiler isn't *required* by the standard to be clever enough to do so (the fact that `bufsize` isn't a constant in C in effect means that the compiler doesn't need to be able to use its value at compile time). The C++ standard is more demanding, `bufsize` is an integer constant expression and the compiler is required to be able to work out its value at compile time.

Answer (score 3):

In C99, this is fine if the code is inside a function; the variable is treated as a run-time value, but arrays can have variable length. It's not allowed if it has static storage.

In C++, this is fine; a `const` integer variable can be used as a compile-time value.

In older versions of C, it wasn't allowed; the variable was a run-time value, and variable-length arrays did not exist.

> Why is it said so?

Because that's how the language designers decided the languages should behave.

Answer (score 3):

C89 doesn't allow this, because a `const int` is not considered a *constant expression*, and the size of an array must be specified as a constant expression.

In C99 (and newer), variable length arrays eliminate the requirement that the size of an array be given as a constant expression, so this is allowed (where a VLA is allowed, which is basically: with auto storage class -- not as a `static` or a global).

C++ requires that the size of an array be specified as a constant expression (like C89), but allows a `const int` as a constant expression<sup>1</sup>, so this is allowed.

---

<sup>1</sup> As @JamesKanze pointed out, *just* being a `const int` doesn't guarantee that a variable's value will be considered a constant expression. Only a `const int` with a visible initializer that is itself a constant expression is allowed -- but those restrictions are met here.

Comment: Just a nit, but an `int const` is only a constant expression if its initializer is visible and is also a constant expression.  Thus: `f( int const n ) { char buf[n]; }` isn't legal (because the initializer isn't visible, and `f() { int const n = g(); char buf[n]; }` isn't legal, because the initializer isn't a constant expression.

Answer (score 2):

In C ***`const` declarations*** do not produce ***constant expressions***, while they do in C++.
So,

```
const int bufsize = 100;
char buf[bufsize];
```

is valid in C++ but not in C.

However, note that Since c99 the C standard allows ***Variable Length Arrays(VLA)***, VLA are not a part of the C++ Standard but most compilers support them through compiler extensions.

Answer (score 1):

> "In C, you will get an error, even though it seems like a rational thing to do. Because bufsize occupies storage somewhere, the C compiler cannot know the value at compile time." Why is it said so?

Because in C, `bufsize` is not const expression; it is a read-only value:

```
const int bufsize = 100; //read-only in C
                         //constant expression in C++
```

The difference between const expression and readonly is that the former means the value is known to the compiler (at compile-time itself) while the latter means the value is readonly, the value isn't known to the compiler.

Note that in C++, `buffsize` and `100` are const expressions, while in C, only `100` is const expression. The size of the declared array needs to be const expression; So the following is allowed only in C++ (and in C99 which allows VLA which is yet another story):

```
char buf[bufsize]; //ok in C++ (and C99)
                   //error in C89, C90
```

Answer (score 0):

#### History of this question traces back to 80's where Late Dennis Ritchie stated

> **By contrast, the apparently most obvious language generalization (that is, allowing general expressions instead of constants in array
>   bounds) complicates the type structure of the language, causes
>   difficulties with the calculus of datatypes, and causes nonuniformity
>   in discovering the sizes of arrays.**
>   *(Extract from Journal of C Language Translation, vol 2 number 2,By Dennis Ritchie)*

With this paper he appealed to the standards body to avoid the use of VLA.

However in later releases of C (C99) this was reviewed and they allowed the use of variable length array under non global scope.

In C++ this is valid as const declared variables are considered constant expression.